# Data-annotation check unique field

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

I tried to check if the username is already exist in the database for a registration system. But after implement this features my registration system doesn't work and he doesn't show me if the username exist !

Model :

```
    public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsUserExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "User already exist!")]
    [Display(Name = "Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "La chaîne {0} doit comporter au moins {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmer le mot de passe ")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe et le mot de passe de confirmation ne correspondent pas.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }
}
```

IsUserExist

```
    public JsonResult IsUserExist(string username)
    {
        var exist = WebSecurity.UserExists(username);
        return Json(!exist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And my view :

```
@model Projet2.Models.RegisterModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "S'inscrire";
}

<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>Créez un nouveau compte.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Formulaire d'inscription</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Lname)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Lname)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fname)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fname)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" />
</fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttonset.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/input-control.js")
}
```

Is it there are errors in my code or I must do something else?

Thanks per advance !

PokeRstarrr

Comment: So you are hitting IsUserExist and WebSecurity.UserExists(username) returns the expected value? You have the proper appSettings in web.config? Also maybe   [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: appSettings is in web.config, but the Data-Annotation seems not to call IsUserExist. I take the code from your URL and adapte it but it's the same he doesn't call IsUserExit.

Comment: So IsUserExist() is in the Account controller? You may need to add [AllowAnonymous] or look at other security issues/filters.

Comment: My bad, you're right it was a problem with security filters. Thanks you for your help ! :)